# Is there a way to use autopy in python 3.11.5

Tags: python, autopy

There is a tutorial I am trying to follow and it requires me to install autopy. I have spent the last house trying to install and and finally watched a video that told me to use python 3.8.0. I install that version of python and then it lets me install autopy. But now there are other libraries that won't work. Is there any way of using autopy on python 3.11.5?